# GPS coordinates dataset of wandering people or tourists

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I would like to use a dataset of GPS coordinates (with time if available) of people (preferable tourists) visiting places in a city.

I would like to use it to compute a map layer with the intensities or frequencies of visits.

I have been using an application to make journeys by my city to make some tests but I would need much more data to accomplish the project.

Where or how can I find it? 
City place or transportation used by people in that city is not a need 
(although is preferable walking people).

Comment: take a look at answers for [**this**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108811/poi-database-of-tourist-attractions-or-poi-database-with-popularity-index) question on GIS forum , it might help .

Comment: @Mokhtar thanks. More than the location of POIs (interesting places to visit) I would like to use the paths that a visitant follows to reach there.

Comment: flickr's search may prove fruitful here; perhaps combining vacation or tourist/tourism tags with images that are geocoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSM has public GPS traces https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces

But you'd have to screen either the GPX files based on GPS coordinates, or text label.

You can use internet search to find keywords:

[image]

And then each trace is individually downloadable, for example:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/Matthew%20Sammon/traces/449560

[image]

[image]

---

Apparently, public GPS traces are available in bulk in the Planet data - [read more.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/36993/112869)

Comment: I would like to thank for your answer. The last link `read more` it does not link any current webpage. May you update the URL, please.

Comment: Openstreetmap offers the routes you commented but they are mostly of hicking activities. It is difficult to find dataset about city tourism.

Comment: I updated the link